# Using secondary domain for Google Hangouts URL

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, google-hangouts, google-workspace-for-business

My primary domain name is `foobar.com`. My secondary domain name is `fizbaz.com`. When I create links in Google Calendar to do a Hangout, the URL always includes `foobar.com` no matter what, but I'd like have it have the `fizbaz.com` name.

There doesn't seem to be a way to change either the primary domain or the Hangouts URL to `fizbaz.com`.

Can anyone help with this? It's pretty much a branding disaster to be forced to use an irrelevant domain name and have to explain to people every time about why your business has some random Hangouts URL.

Answer (score 1):

At this time is not possible, but recently Google added more controls for multi-domain organizations, so the hangouts web address mapping could be added "soon" (could take several months).

**References**
[Feature parity for multi-domain Google Apps instances](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.mx/2015/03/feature-parity-for-multi-domain-google.html)